# No puedo mostrar datos de Lista en View ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lista

Resulta que tengo un servicio WCF, el cual me trae un lista de X de datos (`Nombre, Apellido, Area`). La cual mapeo en una clase para después enviarla a la vista:

**Clase de Mapeo**

```
public class MapaEmpleadoGeneral
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion_Area { get; set; }
    }
```

**CONTROLADOR**

```
public ActionResult Empleados()
        {
            
            var ListadoEmpleados = servEmpleado.ListadoEmpleado();

            List<MapaEmpleadoGeneral> ListaEmpleados = new List<MapaEmpleadoGeneral>();

            foreach(var item in ListadoEmpleados)
            {
                MapaEmpleadoGeneral _item = new MapaEmpleadoGeneral
                {
                    Nombre = item.Nombre,
                    Apellidos = item.Apellidos,
                    Descripcion_Area = item.Descripcion_Area
                };
                ListaEmpleados.Add(_item);
            }

            return View(ListaEmpleados);
        }
```

En la vista tengo esto:

**VIEW**

```
@model IEnumerable<IHR.Models.MapaEmpleadoGeneral>
.
.
.
.
@foreach (var m in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                <div class="profile-widget">
                    <div class="profile-img">
                        <a href="profile.html" class="avatar"><img src="images/avatar-02.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown profile-action">
                        <a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_employee"><i class="fa fa-pencil m-r-5"></i>Editar</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_employee"><i class="fa fa-trash-o m-r-5"></i>Eliminar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="user-name m-t-10 mb-0 text-ellipsis"><a href="profile.html">@m.Nombre</a></h4>
                    <div class="small text-muted">
                        @m.Descripcion_Area
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

La cuestión es que cuando corro la aplicación, me da un error (cosa rara, ya que estoy reutilizando código por lo cual este código ya me ha servido), el cual es:

> El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IHR.svcEmpleado.MapaEmpleadoGeneral]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[IHR.Models.MapaEmpleadoGeneral]'.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cual es el error en mis líneas de código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error indica que el tipo de dato del modelo de la vista es diferente del que controlador está enviando.

El tipo usado en el controlador es `HR.svcEmpleado.MapaEmpleadoGeneral`  y  el tipo que espera la vista es `IHR.Models.MapaEmpleadoGeneral`.

Ambas clases `MapaEmpleadoGeneral`, aunque se sean idénticas, son de espacios de nombres diferentes.

La solución es cambiar el model de la vista para que coincida con el tipo de dato que el controlador envía, o cambiar el tipo de dato que el controlador envía a la vista:

```
@model IEnumerable<IHR.svcEmpleado.MapaEmpleadoGeneral>
```

Comment: Excelente, solo una pregunta, por que en este caso tengo que llamar al servicio y no al modelo (en este caso la clase "MapaEmpleadosGeneral")? Gracias

Comment: Agregué la explicación a la respuesta.